# How can I allow my SQL Server container created by the jenkins contaner to be able to view my host's .bak files?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, continuous-integration, docker-volume

**I would like my SQL Server container created by the jenkins contaner to be able to view my host's .bak files and thus be able to restore some banks. How can I accomplish this task?**

Details of my environment:
I use windows 10 pro and WSL (windows subsystem for linux). I created a jenkins container on the docker that assembles my local dev environment infrastructure. It is the host environment of the Sql Server container and almost all of my infrastructure. About docker daemons I binded between these daemons (host and jenkins daemon).

docker-compose from my jenkins

```
version: "3.7"

#Volume to sql-server-container-dev
volumes:
  jenkins-dev:
    name: jenkins-dev

services:
  
  jenkins-dev-service:
    container_name: jenkins-dev
    hostname: windows-host
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  
    image: jenkins-image-dev
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
     #Bind o daemon docker do host para o container
     - '//var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'

     #Dependencia abstrata
     - 'C:/Projetos/infra_agil/jenkins:/jenkins'
```

docker compose from my sql server

```
version: "3.7"

networks: 
   sql-server-network:
     driver: bridge
     
volumes:
  jenkins-dev:
    external: true

services:
  # Habilite Filesharing se não o sql server não irá subir
  sql-server-db:
    container_name: sql-server-container-dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: sql-server:2019
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: jenkins-dev
        target: /backups
    ports: 
        - "1433:1433"
    networks:
      - sql-server-network
```

The docker-compose from my jenkins is located:

> C:\Projetos\infra_agil\jenkins

The sqlserver docker-compose is located:

> C:\Projetos\infra_agil\jenkins\infra_comum\sql-server

The backup files are located:

> C:\Projetos\infra_agil\jenkins\database\backups

Image that shows the location of these files.
[Image of Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vO5v.png)

I've done several tests. In one of them I managed to 'bind' between the backups folder of the host - jenkins - and the sql server container. However, the sql-server container could not see the files inside the folder, only jenkins could see it.